# Ambiguous types using ListLike

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, strong-typing

I'm writing a function in Haskell to make a histogram from any `ListLike` with `Ord` elements:

```
import qualified Data.ListLike as LL
...
frequencies :: (Ord x, LL.ListLike xs x) => xs -> [(x, Int)]
frequencies xs = LL.map (\x->(LL.head x, LL.length x)) $ LL.group $ LL.sort xs
```

When trying to compile the above code i get an error message about ambiguous types:

```
 Ambiguous type variable `full0' in the constraint:
 (LL.ListLike full0 xs) arising from a use of `LL.group'
 Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
 In the expression: LL.group
 In the second argument of `($)', namely `LL.group $ LL.sort xs'
 In the expression:
 LL.map (\ x -> (LL.head x, LL.length x)) $ LL.group $ LL.sort xs
```

`LL.group` has type `(ListLike full0 full, ListLike full item, Eq item) => full -> full0` which corresponds to `(Eq a) => [a]->[[a]]` speaking in terms of ordinary lists.

I dont understand why there is a  problem with ambigious types. Is Haskell somehow unable to infer that there is such a type as "ListLike with `full` as elements", i.e `full0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is Haskell somehow unable to infer that there is such a type as "ListLike with `full` as elements", i.e `full0`?

No, the problem is there are too many types to choose `full0` from and the Haskell compiler does not know which to use.  Think about it: in general, there can be more than one type `full0` which is a list-like type with `full` as elements: `[full]` or `Data.Sequence.Seq full` or many other choices.  And because of the generality of the definition of `LL.map`, `full0` is *not* constrained to be `[full]` from the return type of the function `frequencies`.

If you want to restrict `full0` to `[full]`, one way to do this is to replace `LL.map` in the definition of `frequencies` with the plain old `map` for lists.

Comment: To be perfectly clear, `full0` is the output type of `LL.group`, which is then an input to `LL.map`, which then outputs yet another type (a plain list here).  This is essentially the same as the `show . read` problem.